# Rails sessions not storing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, session-cookies

I've been looking to store a simple, garden-variety CookieStore session through my controller's create method as it isn't sensitive info. From all I've read on SO, it should be as simple as `session[:key] = value` and we all call it a day, but when I put `p session` in there to debug, it only displays the session_id, _csrf_token, and prev_url keys. Shouldn't there be a `key` key/value pair in there as well? I'm doing a conditional in my view and it relies on the presence of that session.

Is there something that might prevent a session from storing?

Comment: it should be fine, could you post some code you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was trying to store the session before save.

I switched

```
def create
  @lead = Spree::Lead.new(params[:lead])
    session[:newsletter] = "true" if params[:referrer] == "newsletter"
  if @lead.save

  (rest of code)
```

to

```
def create
  @lead = Spree::Lead.new(params[:lead])
  if @lead.save
     session[:newsletter] = "true" if @lead.referrer == "newsletter"


  (rest of code)
```

"Haru, you are such a ninny" 
  -Chris Farley, Beverly Hills Ninja